# POST Doesnt work on my Computer

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Im trying to use Post to read something from my form, but even a simple Example from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp doesn't work. My own code is this:

```
<form id="eingabe" method="post" action="../php/suche.php">
    <input id="suche" name="suche" type="text" size="50px" placeholder="Suche">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**suche.php**

```
 $rows = array();
   if (isset($_POST['suche'])) {
       $suche = $_POST['suche'];
       $sql= "SELECT * FROM Buch WHERE  titel LIKE '%" . $suche . "%' OR autor LIKE '%" . $suche  ."%' OR isbn LIKE '%" . $suche  ."%' OR genre LIKE '%" . $suche  ."%'";
       $result=$conn->query($sql);
       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $titel = $row['titel'];
              $autor = $row['autor'];
              $isbn = $row['isbn'];
              $genre = $row['genre'];
              $preis = $row['preis'];
              $bild = $row['image'];
              $beschreibung = $row['beschreibung'];
              $rows[] = $row;
          }
      }
  }
```

the `var_dump($_POST)` is always `array(0) { }` but in the `var_dump($GLOBALS)`, i can find the word i sending:

```
array(6) { ["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]=> string(10) "suche=test" ["_GET"]=> array(0) { } ["_POST"]=> array(0) { }...
```

**Question is:**

I am using **php7.1**, but already tried older versions.
If i change to GET it works, but i really need to use POST.
I also checked my php.ini but POST is activated and has 128MB for ussage.
Does anyone have an idea why Post doesnt work for me?

PS: A friend of mine is using the exact same code and it works for him perfectly, so its not the code

Comment: I think it may be your browser, because it may cause problem. As you said your code works fine on friends PC. Try another browser as your browser might be affected.

Comment: Are you and your friend running the code on the same server? If not do you and your friend have the same server configuration and re-write rules in place?

Comment: we are woriking lokally, and only the databse is on the server? if this answers your question

Comment: PHP is a server side language, whatever is running it is your server.

Comment: so we both run with PHP Version 7.0.20RC1 and we even use the same php.ini

Comment: @memporer you say you're running this locally, how exactly? as `http://localhost` or directly in your browser as `file:///`?

Comment: Neither have rewrite rules in place?

Comment: what do you use as a `server` ?

Comment: ok you seem to be elsewhere now; so am I and am not going to stare at this section any much longer. If you want attention from someone in particular, @ them, good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://localhost:63342/ShareBook/ShareBook/. php is working fine, it just the POST that doesnt work

Comment: @YvesLeBorg we are using a Raspberry Pi, but as i said, its working for my friend, so its something wrong on my computer

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this -

```
 $rows = array();
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
   $suche = $_POST['suche'];
   $sql= "SELECT * FROM Buch WHERE  titel LIKE '%" . $suche . "%' OR autor LIKE '%" . $suche  ."%' OR isbn LIKE '%" . $suche  ."%' OR genre LIKE '%" . $suche  ."%'";
   $result=$conn->query($sql);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $titel = $row['titel'];
          $autor = $row['autor'];
          $isbn = $row['isbn'];
          $genre = $row['genre'];
          $preis = $row['preis'];
          $bild = $row['image'];
          $beschreibung = $row['beschreibung'];
          $rows[] = $row;
      }
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($rows);
  }
 }else{
   echo "POST method not working";
 }
```

Here if your POST method will not work then you will get an message "POST method not working" and if your POST method is working then you will get your data using print_r() function.

Note - This code is only for the testing purpose, Please modify it as per your need.

Comment: "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in..."

Comment: Should be `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){` - close square bracket was in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry Typing mistake

Comment: i did, no warnings, but still no change, there is still no content in $_POST

Comment: If you are not getting **POST method not working**. That means _POST_ method is working. There might me something else that is wrong. Try printing `$suche`, and see if the data is coming from the form. if the data is coming then print your query string (`$sql`) and copy query and try executing directly into phpmyadmin and see if the query is working. @memporer